# Problems retrieving octet-stream in AngularJS application using Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, rest, internet-explorer-11, restangular, microsoft-edge

In an angularjs application I am making a call to a REST service that returns an octet-stream. The content of the stream is a xml file, that I want to get the content of and then pass onto another control. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE (I have 11, but also saw this in Edge) the content returned looks like garbage (actually a bunch of chinese characters) when I debug through IE  Developer tools, and the subsequent control fails because it is expecting xml.

```
<resource path="/{type}/{modelName}">
  <param name="type" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
  <param name="modelName" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
  <method name="POST">
   <request>
     <representation mediaType="text/plain">
       <param name="request" style="plain" type="xs:string"/>
     </representation>
   </request>
   <response>
     <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
   </response>
  </method>
</resource>
```

And the call looks like:

```
Restangular.one('streams/graphML/' + model.name + '?maxNodes=1000').withHttpConfig(config).get().then(function (response) {
    callback({error: false, data: response});
  },
  function (response) {
    spectrumSdkLog.error(response.data);
    callback({error: true, message: response.data});
  });
```

Any help with why this is would be greatly appreciated. I have been looking for an answer but have yet to find one.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an online example that repros the issue?

Comment: If it's XML, why is it an octet stream? Shouldn't it be `text/xml`? IE is probably trying to parse the file as binary data

Comment: The service was originally used in a Silverlight application to get around timeout issues with long asynchronous calls. The server generates the xml on request and depending on the source could take some time, so we passed a stream that kept the connection alive until closed. This worked fine in IE using Silverlight. 

Not really sure how to simulate this in an online example...